# How can I run a "DESCRIBE" on INFORMATION_SCHEMA views in SQLCompact?

Tags: sql-server-ce

When I want to "`DESCRIBE`" a table in SQL Server or SQL Server CE. I use a query like the following:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE, DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME= 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
```

This returns something similar to a `DESCRIBE` query in Oracle.

However, I cannot find any way to run a query that will show me all of the columns in the views of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (ie. `DESCRIBE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`) . Any idea how to expose those column names and types via a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that, but you can use DbDataReader.GetSchemaTable based on SELECT * FRom the view in ado.net

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing just that in case I cannot find a more elegant way.